# Maximal order of a group algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be an abelian group of order $N$. Let $A$ be the maximal order in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]/\sum_{g \in \Gamma}g$. Then in page $53$, section $8$ of [this paper](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/2137/346_069.pdf?sequence=1) the authors say that
" It is well know that $A$ is unique and it is a product of ring of integers of number fields." The authors also gives some examples below which are the following:

$1)$ For $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $A=\mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{Z}$.

$2)$ For $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then $A=\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

But I do not understand the examples and the fact that $A$ is unique. Since the authors say that it is well known, could anyone provide me with a reference? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short sketch of an explanation; if any part needs expanding let me know.

Because $\Gamma$ is a finite abelian group, the ring $R:=\Bbb{Q}[\Gamma]/\sum_{g\in \Gamma}g$ is a reduced commutative ring that is also a finite dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space. That means $R$ is Artinian, and hence it has only finitely many prime ideals, and they are all maximal. Then by the Chinese remainder theorem the map
$$R\ \longrightarrow\ \prod_{\mathfrak{m}\subset R\text{ maximal}}R/\mathfrak{m},$$
is an isomorphism because $R$ is reduced, where the right hand side is a product of number fields. The maximal order in a number field is its ring of integers, and so the maximal order in $R$ is the product of these rings of integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do you compute the maximal ideals in group rings like $R$ when $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? Also how many maximal ideals will be in $R$?

Comment: Honestly I know nothing about group rings, so all I can say is that rather trivially, the number of maximal ideals in $R$ will be at most $|\Gamma|-1$. Perhaps this is worth making into a new question.

Comment: Could you please explain your statement "the number of maximal ideals in $R$ will be at most $|\Gamma|-1$". Why is it true?

Comment: Because the rank of $R$ is $|\Gamma|-1$, and the rank of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is at least $1$ for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Honestly I was thinking about the problem a bit differently. If we look only at the group ring $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$ then we can decompose it in simple components which should correspond to the number of irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which should correspond to the number of irreducible characters of the group $G$ which takes values in $\mathbb{Q}$. For the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the number of characters is $4$. hence in this case (I think) that $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$ should decompose into $4$ simple components.

Comment: That seems fine. But your question (and the paper) are about $\Bbb{Q}[\Gamma]/\sum_{g\in\Gamma}g$, which then has $3$ simple components. It seems that by the correspondence you describe, maximal ideals of $R$ correspond to conjugacy classes of $\Gamma$.

Comment: But for the group $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, the number of characters of $\Gamma$ with values in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$. So $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$ should have $2$ simple components. Hence I "tend" to believe that $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]/\sum_{g \in \Gamma}g$ has $1$ simple component which is clearly false by the examples of the paper because $A=\mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am trying to find out what is  wrong in my argument.

Comment: I am not familiar with the correspondence you describe in your earlier comment, so I don't know. I suggest you ask a new question. And perhaps accept this answer so the question doesn't end up in the 'unanswered' queue.